# Battery packs without "blip"

Tags: power, usb-power, battery

The Battery pack I am using for the has just one problem... plug in the pack to charge the pack itself, and it blips, rebooting the pi (not the mention shutting down most ungracefully.)

Are there any battery packs known that do NOT have this characteristic?

If not, I have some breakout boards ([like so](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10031)) and the college would let me borrow an oscilliscope to see what the fluctuation is.  If one of my engineering professors helps me fix it, I'll post the solution....

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of that "blip" by adding a supercap (or maybe just a big 6800uF capacitor) to the supply wire of your Pi. They can momentarily power your Pi when the battery pack is flashing off.

There are various ways to implement this:

- Disassemble your power supply and solder the cap to its output jack,
- Peel off the shielding your USB power cable and the insulation on its power (usually red) and ground (usually black) wires and solder your cap there
- Make a two-pin plug with your cap on it and install it on P1 or P5 header
- If you do not plan to install your P5 headers, solder your cap directly there between 5V and GND rails of the Pi

Big normal caps are huge, supercaps can be smaller with a similar capacity. I have not used any supercap (just big normal caps) so I am not very sure there.

Answer (score 1):

I've have a adafruit [USB Battery Pack for Raspberry Pi - 4400mAh](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1565) for a few days and so far its run clean, no blips.  I've powered up-and-down a number of times, and so far all clean.